# Can GDAL be used to load raster data into Postgres/Postgis geodatabase?

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql, loading

I would like to know if GDAL can be used to load raster data to a postgres/postgis geodatabase

I had read that there was problems with the GDAL postgis raster driver?

I was wondering what particular GDAL commands would be used to load the raster data to the geodatabase

I am not sure if GDAL would allow me to load each raster image at a time or require a mosaic to be produced first.

Are there any parameters that can be used/set to improve loading speed?

Comment: Why do you want to load with GDAL and not raster2pgsql which comes packaged with PostGIS?  raster2pgsql uses GDAL.  I think the gdal postgis raster driver is just read-only.

Comment: raster2pgsql allows you to tile rasters, so they are the same coverage in Postgis, but many opertions are quicker, and no, you do not need to mosaic anything, so long as your rasters are properly georerenced.